# Object creation based on a String

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, chatbot

Let's say I'm writing a bot for a chat (discord, telegram, whatever). The bot can handle chat commands (e.g. !join tells it to join a voice channel on the server).

So somewhere in my code I'd have to parse the command, and I'll have something like

```java
String userMessage = getTheMessageTextSomehow();
// Do something with the  message.
```

I'd like to have a Command class for every one of my commands, and every command would implement a execute() method.

My question is: what's the best practice to create those command objects?

The easiest way would be to have a large CommandFactory or whatever class somwhere, that would be like

```java
if(message.equals(JOIN_MESSAGE) {
    return new JoinCommand();
} 
if(message.equals(LEAVE_MESSAGE){
    return new LeaveCommand();
}
//etc...
```

That looks like a bad practice and code smell to me.
Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Maybe the commands could live in some kind of Map, like a HashMap.

Comment: How is it different from having a large factory though? I think it suffers from the same problem - having to define everything in a large `god-object`-kind of thing.

Comment: Yes, but you can set it up once, and you don't have to iterate through a bunch of conditionals every time you process a command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to rely on a `Map` of `Command`s.
I'll make it clear that for this usecase, using the `Function` or `Supplier`, or whatever standard *functional interface* is not idiomatic at all. Avoid it.

We can start by building a `Command` interface

```
interface Command {
   Result execute(); 
}
```

Or if you need to accept an argument

```
interface Command {
   Result execute(final Input input); 
}
```

Which will have the required implementations

```
class JoinCommand implements Command { ... }
class LeaveCommand implements Command { ... }
class NoopCommand implements Command { ... }
```

And so on.
You'll now need to store those definitions in a `key` (the command) - `value` (the implementation) data structure. A `Map` is perfect for that.

As your command definition will be a `String`, then

```
static final Map<String, Command> COMMANDS = new HashMap<>(8);

static {
   COMMANDS.put("join", new JoinCommand());
   COMMANDS.put("leave", new LeaveCommand());
   // And so on
}
```

The usage is pretty simple

```
final String userMessage = getTheMessageTextSomehow();
final String commandStr = extractCommand(userMessage);
final Command command = COMMANDS.getOrDefault(commandStr, NOOP_COMMAND);
command.execute();
```

Or if you'll have to accept an argument

```
command.execute(yourInput);
```

You'll also notice I used `NOOP_COMMAND`, that's just a no-op implementation for `Command` **to avoid dealing with `null`**. It might be, or it might be not, appropriate.

---

If you're on `Java 9+`, the `Map` could also be created using

```
Map.of(
   "join", new JoinCommand(), 
   "leave", new LeaveCommand(),
   // And so on.
)
```

Comment: Why "avoid it"?   It seems like a decent approach to me.  What would you suggest instead?

Comment: @another-dave those interfaces are just too general. I'd keep using them on Streams or for small scope operations. Here we want something that really express what is the intent of those objects. On the long run, being de-coupled from the standard interfaces will also be beneficial. What if another method is required for the exposed signature? Or if it has to carry a field? Implementing standard interfaces would be confusing.

Comment: Oh, I see. I thought your objection was to your own proposed model *in general*, rather than to the specific use of a standard functional interface. On re-reading, I see that's what you said, but I misunderstood.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, it is implemented via mapping. It would be much clearer and readable to implement this with simple `Map`.

For example:

```
Map<String, Command> strategies = new HashMap<String, Command>(){{
  put(JOIN_MESSAGE, new JoinCommand());
  put(LEAVE_MESSAGE, new LeaveCommand());
}};
```

And its usage:

```
Command command = strategies.get(messageType);
```

Moreover, you can define creation strategies (factories) since Java 8 if you need to construct commands depending on some parameters.

```
Map<String, Function<String, Command>> strategies = new HashMap<String, Command>(){{
  put(JOIN_MESSAGE,  param -> new JoinCommand(param));   // or JoinCommand::new
  put(LEAVE_MESSAGE, param -> new LeaveCommand(param));  // or LeaveCommand::new
}};
```

And its usage:

```
Command command = strategies.get(messageType);
command.process(param);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello You try Switch Case statement for it, it's easy to understand and in future if you have any changes then it's easy to update the code.

```
switch(message)
    {
       case JOIN_MESSAGE:
            return new JoinCommand();
            break;

       case LEAVE_MESSAGE:
            return new LeaveCommand();
            break;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how it is different from multiple `if` checks, which I still find to be a code-smell.

Comment: This can also become inefficient if the amount of commands starts to be high.

Comment: yes it's same, the above code is more efficient actually i do't know about the map concept .